# Sum involving hypergeometric 2F2 function

Tags: summation, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to simplify the following sum:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{z^i}{(n-i)!}\,\frac{1}{(1+a)_i\,(1-a)_i}\sum_{j=0}^i(-1+a)_j\,(-1-a)_j\frac{(-z)^j}{j!},
$$
where $n=1,2,\ldots$, $z>0$, $0<a<1$, and $(x)_k=\Gamma(x+k)/\Gamma(x)$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

The inner sum is expressible through the ${}_2F_{2}$ hypergeometric function of the following form: ${}_2F_{2}[1,-i;2-a-i,2+a-i;z]$. The latter is a terminating series, so the entire double sum is a polynomial in $z$ of degree $n$.

My question is to what extent is the entire double sum above can be simplified? For example, can it be reduced to a single hypergeometric function of some sort?

This question was also recently asked [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191790/summation-involving-2f2-hypergeometric-function).